# How to efficiently import user created Widget in MainWindow in PyQt5?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qt-designer

### Situation

I have created my own widget (It is a group box with a lot of another widgets) called `MyWidget` using Qt Designer using the following option:

[Qt Designer Option Chosen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2dedH.png)

After creating the widget, I have added further functionality to it using Python enclosed in file `Hello.py`.

In my main code i.e. `mainwindow`, I have a combo box and two labels.

### My Question

Now I would like to import `MyWidget` (in `Hello.py`) in the main code (in `Main.py`) such that `MyWidget` appears just under the `combobox` in `mainwindow`. How can I do it efficiently?

> Hello.py

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MyWidget(object):
    def setupUi(self, MyWidget):
        MyWidget.setObjectName("MyWidget")
        MyWidget.resize(690, 327)
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(MyWidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.VP_gridLayout_DefProp = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.VP_gridLayout_DefProp.setObjectName("VP_gridLayout_DefProp")
        self.VP_CB_Modulus = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(MyWidget)
        self.VP_CB_Modulus.setObjectName("VP_CB_Modulus")
        self.VP_gridLayout_DefProp.addWidget(self.VP_CB_Modulus, 2, 3, 1, 1)
        self.VP_CB_DT = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(MyWidget)
        self.VP_CB_DT.setObjectName("VP_CB_DT")
        self.VP_gridLayout_DefProp.addWidget(self.VP_CB_DT, 2, 1, 1, 2)
        self.VP_CB_FHC = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(MyWidget)
        self.VP_CB_FHC.setObjectName("VP_CB_FHC")
        self.VP_gridLayout_DefProp.addWidget(self.VP_CB_FHC, 2, 5, 1, 1)
        self.VP_label_Criteria = QtWidgets.QLabel(MyWidget)
        self.VP_label_Criteria.setStyleSheet("font: 75 8pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";")
        self.VP_label_Criteria.setObjectName("VP_label_Criteria")
        self.VP_gridLayout_DefProp.addWidget(self.VP_label_Criteria, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.VP_line_Attenuation = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(MyWidget)
        self.VP_line_Attenuation.setObjectName("VP_line_Attenuation")
        self.VP_gridLayout_DefProp.addWidget(self.VP_line_Attenuation, 1, 1, 1, 3)
        self.VP_CB_PT = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(MyWidget)
        self.VP_CB_PT.setObjectName("VP_CB_PT")
        self.VP_gridLayout_DefProp.addWidget(self.VP_CB_PT, 2, 4, 1, 1)
        self.VP_CB_PC = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(MyWidget)
        self.VP_CB_PC.setObjectName("VP_CB_PC")
        self.VP_gridLayout_DefProp.addWidget(self.VP_CB_PC, 2, 6, 1, 1)
        self.VP_CB_OHT = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(MyWidget)
        self.VP_CB_OHT.setObjectName("VP_CB_OHT")
        self.VP_gridLayout_DefProp.addWidget(self.VP_CB_OHT, 2, 7, 1, 1)
        self.VP_CB_FHT = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(MyWidget)
        self.VP_CB_FHT.setObjectName("VP_CB_FHT")
        self.VP_gridLayout_DefProp.addWidget(self.VP_CB_FHT, 2, 8, 1, 1)
        self.VP_CB_Bearing = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(MyWidget)
        self.VP_CB_Bearing.setObjectName("VP_CB_Bearing")
        self.VP_gridLayout_DefProp.addWidget(self.VP_CB_Bearing, 2, 9, 1, 1)
        self.VP_CB_Pull = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(MyWidget)
        self.VP_CB_Pull.setObjectName("VP_CB_Pull")
        self.VP_gridLayout_DefProp.addWidget(self.VP_CB_Pull, 2, 10, 1, 1)
        self.VP_push_clear = QtWidgets.QPushButton(MyWidget)
        self.VP_push_clear.setObjectName("VP_push_clear")
        self.VP_gridLayout_DefProp.addWidget(self.VP_push_clear, 3, 5, 1, 2)
        self.VP_label_Attenuation = QtWidgets.QLabel(MyWidget)
        self.VP_label_Attenuation.setStyleSheet("font: 75 8pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";")
        self.VP_label_Attenuation.setObjectName("VP_label_Attenuation")
        self.VP_gridLayout_DefProp.addWidget(self.VP_label_Attenuation, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.VP_label_Thickness = QtWidgets.QLabel(MyWidget)
        self.VP_label_Thickness.setStyleSheet("font: 75 8pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";")
        self.VP_label_Thickness.setObjectName("VP_label_Thickness")
        self.VP_gridLayout_DefProp.addWidget(self.VP_label_Thickness, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.VP_radio_grt5 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(MyWidget)
        self.VP_radio_grt5.setObjectName("VP_radio_grt5")
        self.VP_gridLayout_DefProp.addWidget(self.VP_radio_grt5, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.VP_radio_less5 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(MyWidget)
        self.VP_radio_less5.setObjectName("VP_radio_less5")
        self.VP_gridLayout_DefProp.addWidget(self.VP_radio_less5, 0, 2, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.VP_gridLayout_DefProp, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.VP_table_Display = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(MyWidget)
        self.VP_table_Display.setObjectName("VP_table_Display")
        self.VP_table_Display.setColumnCount(4)
        self.VP_table_Display.setRowCount(0)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        item.setFont(font)
        self.VP_table_Display.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        item.setFont(font)
        self.VP_table_Display.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        item.setFont(font)
        self.VP_table_Display.setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        item.setFont(font)
        self.VP_table_Display.setHorizontalHeaderItem(3, item)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.VP_table_Display, 1, 0, 1, 1)

        self.VP_label_Attenuation.setBuddy(self.VP_line_Attenuation)

        self.retranslateUi(MyWidget)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MyWidget)

        #######################################################   
        #Clear Button         
        self.VP_push_clear.clicked.connect(lambda:self.clear_table(self.VP_push_clear))

      #######################################################
    def retranslateUi(self, MyWidget):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MyWidget.setWindowTitle(_translate("MyWidget", "VP"))
        self.VP_CB_Modulus.setText(_translate("MyWidget", "Modulus"))
        self.VP_CB_DT.setText(_translate("MyWidget", "DT:(CAI/CAIE)"))
        self.VP_CB_FHC.setText(_translate("MyWidget", "FHC"))
        self.VP_label_Criteria.setText(_translate("MyWidget", "Criteria"))
        self.VP_CB_PT.setText(_translate("MyWidget", "PT"))
        self.VP_CB_PC.setText(_translate("MyWidget", "PC"))
        self.VP_CB_OHT.setText(_translate("MyWidget", "OHT"))
        self.VP_CB_FHT.setText(_translate("MyWidget", "FHT"))
        self.VP_CB_Bearing.setText(_translate("MyWidget", "Bearing"))
        self.VP_CB_Pull.setText(_translate("MyWidget", "Pull Through"))
        self.VP_push_clear.setText(_translate("MyWidget", "Clear"))
        self.VP_label_Attenuation.setText(_translate("MyWidget", "Attenuation (in dB)"))
        self.VP_label_Thickness.setText(_translate("MyWidget", "Thickness"))
        self.VP_radio_grt5.setText(_translate("MyWidget", ">5mm"))
        self.VP_radio_less5.setText(_translate("MyWidget", "<=5mm"))
        item = self.VP_table_Display.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MyWidget", "Thickness"))
        item = self.VP_table_Display.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("MyWidget", "Attenuation"))
        item = self.VP_table_Display.horizontalHeaderItem(2)
        item.setText(_translate("MyWidget", "Criteria"))
        item = self.VP_table_Display.horizontalHeaderItem(3)
        item.setText(_translate("MyWidget", "KDF"))
        ####################################################### 
    def clear_table(self,button):
        self.VP_table_Display.setRowCount(0)

        Chkbox = [self.VP_CB_Modulus,self.VP_CB_PC,self.VP_CB_FHC,self.VP_CB_DT,self.VP_CB_PT,self.VP_CB_OHT,self.VP_CB_FHT,self.VP_CB_Bearing,self.VP_CB_Pull]   

        for name in Chkbox:
            name.setChecked(False)                        
        #######################################################
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
        #######################################################    
    app = QtCore.QCoreApplication.instance()
    if app is None:
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    MyWidget = QtWidgets.QGroupBox()
    ui = Ui_MyWidget()
    ui.setupUi(MyWidget)
    MyWidget.show()
    app.exec_()
        #######################################################
```

> Main.py

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
        #######################################################
import hello.py
        #######################################################

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
        #######################################################
    def MyWid_groupBox(self):
        self.window = QtWidgets.QGroupBox()
        self.ui     = hello.Ui_MyWidget()
        self.window.show
        #######################################################
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(708, 462)
        MainWindow.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.WheelFocus)
        MainWindow.setTabShape(QtWidgets.QTabWidget.Rounded)

        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)

        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName("gridLayout_2")

        self.VP_push_close = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.VP_push_close.setObjectName("VP_push_close")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.VP_push_close, 3, 1, 1, 1)

        self.line_separate = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.line_separate.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.HLine)
        self.line_separate.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.line_separate.setObjectName("line_separate")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.line_separate, 1, 0, 1, 2)

        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")

        self.label_DefType = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_DefType.setStyleSheet("font: 75 8pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";")
        self.label_DefType.setObjectName("label_DefType")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_DefType, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        self.combo_Deftype = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.combo_Deftype.setObjectName("combo_Deftype")
        self.combo_Deftype.addItem("")
        self.combo_Deftype.addItem("")
        self.combo_Deftype.addItem("")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.combo_Deftype, 0, 1, 1, 1)

        spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(148, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)

        self.gridLayout.addItem(spacerItem, 0, 2, 1, 1)

        self.label_MDOCLink = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_MDOCLink.setStyleSheet("font: 75 8pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";")
        self.label_MDOCLink.setObjectName("label_MDOCLink")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_MDOCLink, 0, 3, 1, 1)

        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.VolPorosity_groupBox, 2, 0, 1, 2)

        self.gridLayout_2.addLayout(self.gridLayout, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_DefType.setBuddy(self.combo_Deftype)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.VP_push_close.clicked.connect(MainWindow.close)                              #Close Button
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))

        self.VP_push_close.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Close"))
        self.label_DefType.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Choose the Type"))
        self.combo_Deftype.setItemText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "-"))
        self.combo_Deftype.setItemText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "X"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

        #######################################################    
    app = QtCore.QCoreApplication.instance()
    if app is None:
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

#    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    app.exec_()
        #######################################################
```

**PS**: Anything between the long hash lines is a code added by me to code generated by using the Qt designer.

Comment: @eyllanesc Would you know anything about this?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question could be find on the following video: [PyQt : Open Other Window When Button Clicked](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dRRpbDFnMHI&list=PL9OFx3Fy8biig64iO6kSorHOX2Dzgqaya&index=2). This is quite useful for understanding the way to link different python files generated from .Ui format using Pyuic5 which is further generated from Qt Designer. This video is specific for PyQt5 and the explanation is just strike on.